# Why does yum update says it is "Installing" one of the packages?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, package-management

When I run `yum update`, it lists the packages that it will upgrade. For one of the packages, `kernel`, it lists it under the "Installing" header. All other packages are listed under the "Upgrading" header. Why does it say that is "Installing" that package? The current version of that package is `4.14.104-95.84.amzn2` and it will be upgraded/installed to `4.14.114-103.97.amzn2`. This is not even a major version change, in which case, it might have made sense. Is there a general case where this happens? Or is this only specific to kernel and related packages, since they are special in a sense?

Comment: Migrated from SO based on feedback there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55976511/why-does-yum-update-says-it-is-installing-one-of-the-packages

Answer (score 2):

From here - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8-beta/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/updating-kernel-with-yum_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel

> The yum package manager always installs a new kernel instead of replacing the current one, which could potentially leave your system unbootable.

The system must be rebooted after installing `kernel` package for consistency, integrity reasons.

Also `yum` handles updating the `kernel` package so that end-user need not worry about upgrading or installing it.